# How do I build runkit for Windows?

Tags: php, windows, runkit

I am trying to use Runkit on a windows machine. PHP version is 5.6.14, windows version is Windows 8 Enterprise, runkit version is 1.0.4.

I've already built it. I confirmed that the DLL in the correct directory.

I added the following line to php.ini

```
extension=php_runkit.dll
```

I called the `runkit_superglobals()` function and I got the following output.

```
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:\xampp\php\ext\php_runkit.dll' - The specified module could not be found.
 in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Call to undefined function runkit_superglobals() in V:\inventory2\tests\bootstrap.php on line 5
```

I went back to the php directory and ran

```
deplister ext\php_runkit.dll
```

The output was

```
php5.dll,NOTFOUND
MSVCR110.dll,OK
KERNEL32.dll,OK
```

I confirmed that I have `php5ts.dll` in the php directory and as stated above I am running php version 5.6.14.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your PHP is x64 and your DLL is x86 or vice versa.

Comment: They are both 32 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Just try out one of these DLLs: https://github.com/Crack/runkit-windows

Comment: I can't run binaries from an unknown source.